# Animate Javascript show / hide button

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, show-hide

I'm building a site and in the header there is a mail icon. When you click the icon an input field and submit button appear so people can sign up for a newsletter. Is there a way to use width instead of using display:none and display:inline? So when you click the mail icon the input field is animated to slide out from the left rather than just instantly appear?

Here's the javascript code im using...

```
  <!--Show & Hide Script Start-->
<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id1) {
if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='H'){
document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'S';
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';

}else{
document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'H';
document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'inline';

}
}
</script>
<!--Show & Hide Script End-->
```

Comment: Use jQuery which has `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions.

Comment: that code is oldschoooooool =D Read into some modern javascript. `language="Javascript"` looks like your sources are from the last century.

Comment: I vote you also use jQuery, make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

**Welcome to the wonderful world of jQuery!**

Include this in your `<head></head>`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The rework your function to this:

```
function setVisibility(id1) {
  if($('#bt1').val() == 'H'){
    $('#bt1').val('S');
    $('#' + id1).fadeOut();
  }
  else{
    $('#bt1').val('H');
    $('#' + id1).fadeIn();
  }
}
```

If you want, you can even take it a step further and set up your click events in jQuery as well...

```
$(function(){ //this part of the code wait until the DOM has loaded to execute
  $('[ID or Class selector for the button]').click(function(){
    setVisibility([string identifier for your element to hide/show]);
  });
});
```